# Finding diagonal matrices with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all diagonal 3 x 3 matrices A with complex entries such that 
$A^2$=$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Can anyone please help me how to start this? I'm not sure how I should approach this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix has the form $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b & 0\\ 0 & 0 &c\end{bmatrix}$$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$. Now what must $A^2$ look like?

Comment: does that mean that$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
        a^2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & b^2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$? so does complex entries mean that entries should be in the a+bi form???

Comment: Yes, each entry has that form. Now compare this to the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: So I can do, something like (a+bi)^2 = 2 and same with -1?

Comment: Yup! That should do it.

Comment: @user425030: But you already know both square roots of $2$, and both square roots of $-1$, so no need to solve $(s+ti)^2 =\, ...$. Also, no need to express the diagonal entries in the form $s + ti$; just write them as you would normally do.

Answer (score 0):

@Zack Cramer has done the heavy lifting.

In the complex plane, the $n$th root of unity has produces $n$ points on the unit circle. For the square root, $n=2$: $\theta_1 = 0$, $\theta_2 = \pi$. When $z = 2$,
$$
  \sqrt{z} = \pm  \sqrt{2} 
$$